# How to run forever without sudo on Ec2

Tags: npm, forever

The title is pretty much tells what the question is about. I am trying to use forever to start a script on Ec2 but it does not work unless I use sudo.

If I start without sudo, I get

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: ci.js
```

But when I do `forever list`

```
info:    No forever processes running
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run `forever list` under same user you've started **forever** (it seems like you are doing that right).

Try to check `ps aux | grep node` after you do `forever start`. Maybe you haven't started any process (because of errors in command line or in your NodeJS file) so `forever list` returns empty list.

p.s. I've checked forever on my machine and it is behaving exactly as you said - if i run it under my 'ubuntu' user -> list of running is empty even though process is alive... Seem like a bug in **forever**.